# "onmouseover" and "onmouseout" not working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to achieve something quite simple. Whenever a user hovers over an element, I want a JavaScript function to run that makes another div visible. I tried using `onmouseover` and `onmousedown` to achieve this, but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to.

I set up a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YSbakker/L4Hzw/4/)

Comment: here : http://jsfiddle.net/L4Hzw/7/

Comment: You are calling function `showMenu` and `hideMenu` even when they are not define. You put them on `onLoad` event. Now, when I changed to `No wrap - in head`, it works. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Hzw/6/)

Comment: pure-js people - i love them!

Comment: @doniyor I love myself too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working Fine for me.

Just wrap your `javascript` code in `<head>`.

as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMenu() {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "block";
}

function hideMenu() {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="button" onmouseover="showMenu()" onmouseout="hideMenu()"></div>
<div id="menu"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L4Hzw/8/

OR you can use: `window.function_name=function(){ }` to make your code work, without wrapping it inside `<head><script>`

as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.showMenu=function() {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "block";
}

window.hideMenu=function() {
    document.getElementById("menu").style.display = "none";
}
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L4Hzw/10/

In your fiddle, It wasnt working because You were calling functions `showMenu` and `hideMenu` when they were not defined. So to eliminate that (To define them for current document inside current window) we can use `window.function_name=function(){ }` where window is global object in javascript referning to the documents parent element (Method 2)

OR

we can predefine the function in `<head>` tag of current document. (Method 1)

Comment: Yea, well I can only accept an answer after like 10 minutes of asking the question... :)

Comment: Using "on" event attributes has not been recommended for some time - "These attributes should be avoided. This makes the markup bigger and less readable. Concerns of content/structure and behavior are not well-separated, making a bug harder to find. Furthermore, usage of event attributes almost always causes scripts to expose global functions on the Window object, polluting the global namespace." - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Event_attributes. I'd strongly suggest using addEventListener to attach the event, which would not require the functions be placed in head

Comment: @pwdst, I know that you can use `addEventListener` instead of `on`. But OP's code was using `onEventType`. I've just edited that.